# How to get flash messages to work in Hanami

Tags: hanami

I'm trying to figure out how to get flash messages to work in Hanami.  The only reference to flash messages that [I've found in the official docs](http://hanamirb.org/guides/1.1/actions/testing/#flash-messages) are about testing, not actually implementing.  If I overlooked something, please point me in the right direction.

I also found the [Hanami::Action::Flash](https://github.com/hanami/controller/blob/master/lib/hanami/action/flash.rb) class in the source, but haven't been able to discern from that what I'm doing wrong.

So, I forked the official bookshelf demo app and [added what I think](https://github.com/jsgarvin/bookshelf/commit/a4027fc3edeadb2b832b7e2ec5c5480a728b6d11) is a super rudimentary demonstration of the flash message not working as I think it should, based on what I've read, immediately after creating a book. I feel like the message added in the create action should be visible in here somewhere, but all the index page shows (immediately after the redirect), is...

```
<div id='flash'>#<Hanami::Action::Flash:0x7f442c865408 {}></div>
<div id='message'></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have sessions enabled? `flash` is exposed by default as you're using Hanami 1.1.

Then set it in the action `flash[:some_notice] = "Test"` and use it in a template.

regards,
Sebastjan